# With Underscore.js - Can you _.groupBy a Key with multiple Values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

I am trying to put a group together that has two possible values.  Fiddle to help http://jsfiddle.net/gJPHw/276/.

This works:

```
$scope.newGroup = _.groupBy($scope.data, {rankNum: '6H'});
```

But what I want is:

```
$scope.newGroup = _.groupBy($scope.data, {rankNum: '6H' || '6Y'});
```

Is this possible to do?  The documentation on it doesn't make sense to me - http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy

Or could you do it by substring of 6. substring (0,1) === '6'

Or even something on the lines of the below.  It doesn't work as it returns object object.

```
$scope.newGroupH = _.groupBy($scope.data, {rankNum: '6H'});
$scope.newGroupY = _.groupBy($scope.data, {rankNum: '6Y'});
$scope.newGroupHY = $scope.newGroupH + $scope.newGroupy;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's sounds like a good fit for [_.partition](http://underscorejs.org/#partition). It splits an array in two; one array contains all the items that satisfy a predicate and the other contains all that don't.

```
var groups = _.partition(arr, function(item){
    return item.rankNum == '6H' || item.rankNum == '6Y';
})
```

This results in groups[0] containing all items with a rankNum of 6H or 6Y and groups[1]  containing all the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can do it, to an extent. But you need to use a function instead of an object.

```
$scope.newGroup = _.groupBy($scope.data, function (d) {
    return d.rankNum.substring(0,1);
});
```

That will group by the first letter of `rankNum`. If you put a boolean check like `rankNum === '6H'`, it returns an array of `true` and an array of `false`, since that is what you are returning. I'm not sure how you would group specifically by two values, unless you do the boolean check and then do something with the `true` array that is returned.

If you are only looking for those two values, then `_.filter` would be better.

Comment: I am going to use it in an ng-repeat groupBy:  So I want to have each group with 6 in one div and the others in another. So 6H and 6Y repeat together.

Comment: Also, I have null values that are throwing an error for substring.